# Would you place an implant "in" or "on" your jawbone?

Tags: word-usage, grammaticality

In the sentence, "The doctor will place the implant on your jawbone" would you use "on" or "in"?

Comment: That depends on whether it's being implanted ***in*** the jawbone or ***on*** it.  Will any part of the jawbone be cut away or removed during the process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering that the implant is inserted into the jawbone, "in" tends to be much more usual than "on".

When reference is made to the action, "into" is even more usual than "in".

Compare:

- He **has** a defective implant in his jawbone / The implant in his jawbone lasted ten years. (state or condition)
- The dentist took three hours to place the implant **into** his jawbone. ("in" is, of course, also possible.) (action or movement)

Answer (score 2):

The word "implant", from latin roots, literally means "plant into". In modern usage it still means embed, put into, etc. So for most uses implants go in.

OTOH, since our interiors are not homogeneous, there are circumstances where both "in" and "on" might make sense, e.g. "A subglandular breast implant is set on the pectoral muscle."